# Why won't my https://domain forward to www?

Tags: ssl, heroku, https, dns, godaddy-api

I have a website for my podcast built with Python / Django that is hosted on Heroku: https://dinpodcast.herokuapp.com/

I have a custom domain parked on GoDaddy, `dinpodcast.com`, that has a www CNAME directing to my heroku application.  This works just fine: https://www.dinpoddcast.com

I wanted dinpodcast.com to redirect to the www website, so I have the following domain forwarding set up on Godaddy:

[image]

This also works great, for the most part.  Now, when I enter `http://dinpodcast.com`, or just `dinpodcast.com`, both will redirect to `https://www.dinpodcast.com`.

Here's the problem.  When I enter the naked domain WITH HTTPS, so when I enter `https://dinpodcast.com` into a browser's address bar, I get the following response:

[image]

Here's what I THINK is happening.  My SSL certificate is provided by Heroku under their  Automated Certificate Management program.  So, I assume that since I don't have an SSL certificate with GoDaddy, it's timing out trying to find one before it can redirect to my www subdomain.  Would this be correct?  If so, is there any way around this WITHOUT buying an SSL certificate with GoDaddy? If that's not what's happening, then what is and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

When you create an ssl certificate in your domain do you include your root domain?  Tried using this [tool](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=dinpodcast.com) in your root domain and it seems that there is no ssl certificate. However the subdomain https://dinpodcast.herokuapp.com/ has one. I suggest putting an ssl certificate in all subdomain and root domain that you are using.

I also checked the root domain’s IP address using this [tool](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/) and checked port 443 using another [tool](https://www.ipfingerprints.com/portscan.php) and apparently the port is closed. Double check your firewall and make sure 443 is open.